# Perforce RCS keywords expansion

Tags: perforce, keyword

Perforce [manual](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.091/manuals/p4guide/ab_filetypes.html) says that if you want to automatically expand RCS keywords in file contents, you have to specify some type for them (i.e. +k or +ko).

Is there a way to specify file type based on it's extension globally for the whole depot or its subdirectory?

For example, Subversion [has](http://fixlinux.com/2006/07/24/subversion-and-keyword-substitution/) such a feature called auto-props.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define a "typemap" which will automatically assign a default filetype based on extension, and hence have "text+ko" the default.

http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/typemap.html

Comment: Note that the typemap only applies to new files; you will have to open any existing files for edit, change their filetype, and submit.